# Converting "tweets" to HTML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter

I'm looking for a solution to "linkify" (twitters term, not mine) tweets - to ensure that @names are correctly linked, at that html links are ready for use too prior to displaying the tweet in a uiwebview

I can see a couple of potential routes

- NSScanner based solution where I look for an @ and then the next " " and link everything between. Do same for http://

  Use [Twitter Anywhere linkifier](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere) in a UIWebView, which just feels wrong

  Some clever regex

So before I reinvent any wheels, has anyone got any advice, done this, know of a prewritten class, or anything else I've forgotten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the API? I believe there's now an `entities` payload on each tweet that identifies where things like URLs, hashtags and usernames are within the text of a tweet.

I'd verify that's there myself, but I'm on a locked down corporate network at the moment.

**Edit:**

Here's a link to their announcement of the functionality - http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-api-announce/browse_thread/thread/9b869a9fe4d4252e?hl=en#

Comment: unfortunately as per @daryn's suggestion, I'm receiving a pre-processed list of tweet-like-things - not from twitter but from a 3rd party feed. It doesn't include that info.

Comment: I was looking for a library to do that for me last year, but couldn't find anything. The problem is that there are quite a lot of edge cases, so implementing it yourself isn't trivial. Given that the official API now includes the entities, I've a feeling you might be out of luck. Sorry! :(

Comment: yeh. I've been looking too (hence the question). Maybe I'll try bouncing the requests back via the API. @rse!

Answer (score 2):

Check out this page from the twitter documentation:

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_entities

Comment: unfortunately I'm receiving a pre-processed list of tweet-like-things - not from twitter. The tweet_entities library might be handy if I had any knowledge of Ruby - but sadly I don't